# Windows 10 Getting current processes explorer vs Explorer.EXE

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, windows-10

Using C# in Unity3D, running Windows 10 I have an app that quits Windows explorer (the os ui no the browser).

However, it seems that when the os first starts the process is called "Explorer.EXE" after I kill windows explorer and restart it, using Application.OpenURL("C:\Windows\explorer.exe"), I find that the process is now called "explorer".

Does anyone know why the seemingly same process has two different names?

To rephrase this to hopefully fit in with site standards; 
From my understanding, shouldn't I only need to find the process called "explorer"? And am I causing an unforeseen issue by killing "Explorer.EXE".

Below is my code

```
public void KillExplorer()
{
    // when coomputer first starts, I can find the explorer with Process.GetProcessesByName("Explorer.EXE"). 
    // After I kill explorer this no longer works. Process.GetProcessesByName("Explorer.EXE") retuns a empty array
    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("Explorer.EXE"))
    {
        try {
            p.ForceKill();
        } catch(Exception e){
            print("unable to kill explorere "+ e);
        }
    }

    // 
    // after I kill the explorer once, I can find the explorer with Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")
    // but if I use this after the computer has just restarted Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer") returns an empty array
    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"))
    {
        try {
            p.ForceKill();
        } catch(Exception e){
            print("unable to kill explorere "+ e);
        }
    }
}

public void LaunchExplorer()
{
    string path = "C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe";
    Application.OpenURL(path);
}
```

Comment: 1. why do you need to kill the explorer process? 2. what is the problem?

Comment: Why on earth do you need to kill and/or restart the explorer.exe? That is a bad idea....

Comment: This app runs on a touch screen kiosk. Win 8 and above have global touch gestures that allow users to exit the app and/or gain access to other parts of the os. There are other methods to disable these global gestures however they don't work on all hardware configs. Disabling the os gui is the only surefire way to prevent users from gaining unwanted access.

Answer (score 1):

[`GetProcessesByName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't return the executable filename, rather the "friendly" process name. Probably `explorer` is started in a different way when it is recovering from a crash, which results in it getting a different name. Just search for both `explorer.exe` and `explorer`.